# Carousel Indicator shape

Tags: html, css

I have code for a carousel I created. I am now trying to change the shape of the carousel-indicators from the circles to squares. I tried using `border-radius:0px;` but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Anything helps, thanks.

```css
<style>
.pic{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.carousel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    widht:100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 100;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.carousel-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#008c6c;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #008c6c;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3{
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 100px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.HRConnectImage
{width:375px;
padding-top:50px;
display:inline-block;}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet{
    color: #008c6c;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#p
{
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="carousel"> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true" Checked/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
  <img class="pic" src="">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-3" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="">
      </div>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-1" for="carousel-3">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-1" for="carousel-2">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-2" for="carousel-1">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-2" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-3" for="carousel-2">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-3" for="carousel-1">›</label> 

      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-1">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-2">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">•</label> </li> 

      </ol> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: The circles that come up when you hover on the arrows, or the circles below the slides? Or both

Comment: Aren't those bullets just rendered `•`s? In which case, use a different character.

Comment: 3 circles on the bottom

Comment: I are the ones for the arrows border-radius on the class `.carousel-control`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circular carousel indicator isn't made with CSS borders, it's the "bullet" character •, just use e.g. "black small square" ▪ instead:

```css
<style>
.pic{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.carousel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    widht:100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 100;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.carousel-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#008c6c;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #008c6c;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3{
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 100px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.HRConnectImage
{width:375px;
padding-top:50px;
display:inline-block;}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet{
    color: #008c6c;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#p
{
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="carousel"> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true" Checked/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
  <img class="pic" src="">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-3" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="">
      </div>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-1" for="carousel-3">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-1" for="carousel-2">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-2" for="carousel-1">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-2" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-3" for="carousel-2">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-3" for="carousel-1">›</label> 

      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-1">▪</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-2">▪</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">▪</label> </li> 

      </ol> 
   </div> 
</div>
```